# Неверный вывод в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Доброго времени суток!

Опять я с какой то мелочью, судя по всему :)

Имеется ДЗ:

> Есть два юнита, каждый из них называется «Воин». Каждому
> устанавливается здоровье в 100 очков. Они бьют друг друга в случайном
> порядке. Тот, кто бьёт, здоровья не теряет. У того, кого бьют, оно
> уменьшается на 20 очков от одного удара. После каждого удара надо
> выводить сообщение, какой юнит атаковал и сколько у противника
> осталось здоровья. Как только у кого-то заканчивается ресурс здоровья,
> программа завершается сообщением о том, кто одержал победу.

Выполнил его по примеру, но даже в том примере который я нашел имеется такая же проблема как и у меня.

Код следующий:

```
import random


def hit(target, target1):
    if target.health > 0:
        target.health -= 20
        if target1 == warrior_1:
            target1 = 'Воин_1'
        elif target1 == warrior_2:
            target1 = 'Воин_2'
        print(target1, ' атакует')
        print(target.health, ' осталось')
    elif target.health == 0:
        print(target1, ' выиграл')


class Warrior:
    def __init__(self, health):
        self.health = health


warrior_1 = Warrior(100)
warrior_2 = Warrior(100)

q = int(input('Введите 1 для атаки, 2 для прекращения работы программы: '))

while q != 2:
    if q == 1:
        j = random.randint(1, 3)
        if j % 2 == 0:
            hit(warrior_2, warrior_1)
            q = int(input('Введите 1 для атаки: '))
        else:
            hit(warrior_1, warrior_2)
            q = int(input('Введите 1 для атаки: '))
    else:
        print('Неверный ввод!')
        break
```

Проблема в конечном выводе информации. После того как у одного из юнитов уровень здоровья достигает 0, вместо того чтобы вывести информацию:

```
Воин_№ выиграл!
```

Выходит следующее:

```
Введите 1 для атаки: 1
<__main__.Warrior object at 0x000001FB8E12AFD0>  выиграл
Введите 1 для атаки: 1
<__main__.Warrior object at 0x000001FB8E12AF70>  выиграл
Введите 1 для атаки: 2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

До тех пор, пока программу не завершить.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться и понять "что я упустил?"

Заранее спасибо! :)

P.S.: Не судите строго :)

Comment: Когда вы делаете `print(target1, ' выиграл')` переменная `target1` - это у вас всё ещё экземпляр класса.  В другой ветке if вы его преобразуете в текст, а в этой нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очевидно, что `target` есть экземпляр класса `Warrior`, следовательно - чего вы хотите при преобразовании объекта в строку?

Есть два пути:

### Первый

#### Добавляем свойство `Name`

```
class Warrior:
    def __init__(self, health: int, name: str):
        self.health = health
        self.name = name
```

И тогда:

```
print(target1.name, ' атакует')
```

### Второй

#### Переопределяем `__str__`

```
class Warrior:
    def __init__(self, health: int, name: str):
        self.health = health
        self.name = name
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

И тогда:

```
kek = Warrior(100, 'lol')
print(str(kek))  # lol
```

Comment: print можно вызывать без явного преобразования в str.

Comment: @GrAnd, согласен полностью. Это все мои болезни мании явной типизации :D

Comment: Спасибо большое!:)

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю насчёт выхода из цикла. Проще всего бросить исключение о выходе, для питона это в общем-то нормальный способ:

```
def hit(target, target1):
    ...
    elif target.health == 0:
        print(target1, ' выиграл')
        raise SystemExit
```

Другой вариант - возвращать что-то из функции `hit` и проверять, что вернулось, чтобы прервать цикл:

```
def hit(target, target1):
    if target.health > 0:
        ...
        return False
    elif target.health == 0:
        print(target1, ' выиграл')
        return True

...

        if j % 2 == 0:
            if hit(warrior_2, warrior_1):
                break
            q = int(input('Введите 1 для атаки: '))
        else:
            if hit(warrior_1, warrior_2):
                break
            q = int(input('Введите 1 для атаки: '))
...
```

Comment: Круто! Спасибо большое :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import random


class Warrior:
    def __init__(self, name: str, power: int = 20, health: int = 100):
        self.name = name
        self.power = power
        self.health = health

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def attack(self, other: 'Warrior') -> bool:
        """ Attack other warrior """
        print(f'{self} is attacking {other}!')
        return other.damage(self.power)

    def damage(self, power: int = 20) -> bool:
        """ Decrease health and return true if dead """
        self.health -= power
        is_dead = self.health <= 0

        if not is_dead:
            print(f'{self} have {self.health} points of health left!')
        else:
            print(f'{self} is dead!!!')

        return is_dead


if __name__ == '__main__':
    battle = [
        Warrior('Warrior 1', power=31, health=110),
        Warrior('Warrior 2', power=33, health=100),
        Warrior('Warrior 3', power=30, health=120),
        Warrior('Warrior 4', power=29, health=130),
        Warrior('Warrior 5', power=30, health=120),
    ]

    while len(battle) > 1:
        try:
            command = int(input('\nInput 1 for attack or 2 for stats and 3 for exit: ').strip())
        except ValueError:
            print('Wrong input! Try again.')
        else:
            if command == 1:  # Make a random attack
                random.shuffle(battle)
                warrior_a = battle[0]
                warrior_b = battle[1]

                warrior_b_is_dead = warrior_a.attack(warrior_b)
                if warrior_b_is_dead:
                    del battle[1]

            elif command == 2:  # Show stats
                for warrior in battle:
                    print(f'{warrior} - {warrior.health} points of health and {warrior.power} power.')

            elif command == 3:  # Finish
                sys.exit()

            else:
                print(f'Unknown command {command}! Try again.')

    print(f'{battle[0]} WIN!!!')
```